# Not inherit some (chosen) methods from derived classes

Tags: python, inheritance

Say that, for example, I have two (python (3.3)) classes a and b with their own methods:

```
class a:
    def m1(self):
        print("Hi 1")
    def m2(self):
        print("Hi 2")
        ##...other methods...
class b(a):
    def k1(self):
        print("Other hi")
```

How do I make it so that class `b` inherits all methods from `a` except (for example) `m2`? (besides copy/paste, that doesn't count.) So the expression `a.m2()` would be legitimate, but `b.m2()` would throw an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Any chance that Python allows you to define `b.m2()` to throw that error directly?  I mean to say that you could override the function definition as `throw new AttributeError()` (or whatever the appropriate syntax is)...

Comment: Instead, *don't inherit from a* is the right solution. Just copy methods from `a` as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the effect that you want by making 'a' and 'b' siblings rather than parent and child. This might work for you:

```
class p:
    def m1(self):
        print("Hi 1")

class a(p):
    def m2(self):
        print("Hi 2")

class b(a):
    def k1(self):
        print("Other hi")
```

So these methods are now all valid, the others will throw AttributeErrors:

```
a.m1()
a.m2()
b.m1()
b.k1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that? The whole *point* of class inheritance is to be able to test that instances of `b` are also instances of `a`; `isinstance(b(), a)` is `True` *for a reason*. By removing methods from `b` you are breaking that model badly.

Instead make `a` have fewer methods, and add `c` to have those that `b` doesn't need:

```
class a:
    def m1(self):
        print("Hi 1")
        ##...other methods...

class b(a):
    def k1(self):
        print("Other hi")

class c(a):
    def m2(self):
        print("Hi 2")
```

Or, you could *not inherit from `a`* and just copy methods from `a` as needed:

```
class b:
    # copied methods
    m1 = a.m1

    def k1(self):
        print("Other hi")
```

Now `b` isa `a` is no longer true, the expectation that all of `a`'s methods are implemented won't be there anymore.

If `a` is entirely out of your control and there are too many methods to copy, perhaps use proxying with `__getattr__` and passing through anything but `m2`. A last ditch method could be to implement `m2` and raise `AttributeError`, but that should be a last resort only.

Comment: There would be a lot of copied code so I think I'll stick with your second option. Thank you, accepting answer after cooldown period.

Comment: @Thornshadow17432: Glad to have been of help! Out of curiosity; what does Kevin's answer add to mine that you accepted his post?

Answer (score 0):

If `b` inherits from `a`, it's supposed to inherit every method. That's inheritance about. But if it's necessary to do this (*note that is not recommended*) you could override the `m2()` method, so it raises an `Exception` when called.

```
class b(a):
    def m2(self):
        raise Exception("...")
```

Answer (score 0):

That does not really make sense. The point of inheritance is so that the inheriting object is exactly compatible to the base type. This is the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): Wherever an object of the original type is acceptable, an object of the derived type also will be.

If you change your derived type to not have some members of the base type, then you are violating this principle. With the dynamic typing in Python, it wouldn’t be that much of a problem but it’s still violating the idea behind it.

So you really just shouldn’t do that.